# How come the よう in ~ようものなら can modify a noun?

Tags: grammar

I have the sentence in my book:
昔は、若い女性が男性と二人で出かけようものなら、町中のうわさになったものだ。

I was wondering if this means that it is possible to modify nouns with the volitional form. I have so far heard that it isn't, which makes this grammar point confusing. Could someone give me an explanation as to how to understand ~ようものなら in the above sentence? Is it like, "If women WISHED to go out  with men..."? Or does the volitional have some other interpretation here?

Comment: Interesting question. Some other cases of noun-modifying volitionals: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E4%BA%BA%22

Comment: Who told you it modified a noun in that sentence?  Read my answer.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya, I know the question is not stated that way, but given that the etymology of ものなら involves a formal noun もの, I think it's a fair question to ask whether volitionals modifying nouns have ever been productive, and under what circumstances.

Comment: @dainichi There is also the expression 成【な】ろう事【こと】なら which supports the idea of some level of past productivity of volitionals modifying nouns.

Comment: @rintaun, ah yes, good find! I'm definitely drawing a mental parallel to subjunctive/conjunctive/irrealis moods in IE languages, which also tend to serve volitional purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, ものなら is one word. It is a conjunctive particle that has the same meaning as ～～としたら = "if one were to try ~~ing".

"In the old days, if a young woman were to try going out with a man just the two of them, it would be the talk of the town."

SVP DO NOT take my English TL too literally; English is my worst language.

Comment: I presumed もの was a noun and なら was a particle... But if I am to think of it as a particle and a whole... I guess that might work too!

Your English is great don't worry about it. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: English is my worst language >> Lol you're being sarcastic right?

Comment: What about your French or Chinese then!?

Comment: For what it's worth, @TokyoNagoya didn't claim to have poor English; just that it's the worst of all the languages (s)he knows.

Comment: @istrasci え、そういう意味なの？